# What are the criteria for being able to set object related data in memory?

Tags: apex, relationships

**First, all the background information**

I'm not entirely sure if `Related Data` is the proper thing to call this, but it's the best/most concise label I can think up.

As an example, take the following query

```
[SELECT Id, Subject, Opportunity.Name, Opportunity.Account.Name, Opportunity.OwnerId 
  FROM Case 
  LIMIT 1]
```

In this query, `Opportunity.Name`, `Opportunity.Account.Name`, and `Opportunity.OwnerId` are what I'd call `related data`. In short, any data on an object that you can get via [a relationship query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using.htm#sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_using).

A few months ago, while working on a project, I found that I was able to convince Apex to allow me to set related data on instances of various `sObjects` in memory. For me, this mainly has applications in unit testing the individual units of work in my trigger framework, where I'm injecting a class that wraps the trigger context variables.

As an example let's say we have two sObjects, `CustomObject1__c` and `CustomObject2__c`. There is a lookup relationship, `CustomObject1__c` is the parent and `CustomObject2__c` is the child. Let's call the lookup field (on `CustomObject2__c`) `CustObj1_Lookup__c`.

Given that, in Apex, we are able to write and execute the following:

```
CustomObject1__c testObj1 = new CustomObject1__c(
    Custom_Field1__c = 'foo'
);

// Setting 'related data' can be done in the sObject's constructor,
// or through testObj2.put('CustObj1__r', testObj1);,
// or through testObj2.CustObj1__r = testObj1;
CustomObject2__c testObj2 = new CustomObject2__c(
    Custom_Field2__c = 'bar',
    CustObj1__r = testObj1
);

// If in a unit test, we can use system.assertEquals().
// Otherwise, debug statements or checkpoints in the dev console can be used.
// If this compiles, but can't execute, then we'd get some type of exception on the second assertion
system.assertEquals('foo', testObj1.Custom_Field1__c);
system.assertEquals('foo', testObj2.CustObj1__r.Custom_Field1__c);
```

**The Issue**

Today, while writing a unit test, I ran into an error while attempting to set related data in memory.

The relevant piece of code is this:

```
Service_Order_Product_Detail__c newSOPD = new Service_Order_Product_Detail__c(
    Id = olid6.Service_Order_Product_Detail__c,
    Current_Quantity__c = 1,
    Current_MRR__c = 1,
    New_Quantity__c = 1,
    New_MRR__c = 1,
    NRR__c = 1,
    Allocated_Capital__c = 4
);

olid6 = new OpportunityLineItem_Detail__c(
    Id = olidIds.get('olid6Id'),
    Service_Activation_Status__c = 'Cancelled',
    Service_Order_Product_Detail__c = newSOPD.Id,
    Opportunity__r = new Opportunity(Id = olid6.Opportunity__c),
    Service_Order_Product_Detail__r = newSOPD,    // <== This is the line causing the issue
    Opportunity__c = olid6.Opportunity__c,
    Current_Quantity__c = 0,
    Current_MRR__c = 0,
    New_Quantity__c = 0,
    New_MRR__c = 0,
    NRR__c = 0,
    Type__c = 'Pending Churn',
    Type_Category__c = 'Hard Disco'
);
```

In this code, `Service_Order_Product_Detail__c` is the parent, and `OpportunityLineItem_Detail__c` is the child, and `OpportunityLineItem_Detail__c.Service_Order_Product_Detail__c` is the lookup field.

There is also another lookup relationship between `Opportunity` (parent) and `OpportunityLineItem_Detail__c` (child).

When I attempt to save the class with this code fragment in it, I get an error.

> Field is not writeable: Service_Order_Product_Detail__r

When I comment out the line `Service_Order_Product_Detail__r = newSOPD,`, still setting the opportunity related data in memory, it works just fine.

I've also been able to successfully set related data on `OpportunityLineItem`, which in my org has a lookup to `Service_Order_Product__c`.

I've also succeeded in setting `Account` related data on an `Opportunity` instance (In my org, `Opportunity` has a formula field that references `Account`), and succeeded in setting `Service_Order_Product__c` related data on a `Service_Order_Product_Detail__c` instance (SOP being the master, SOPD being the detail, and a formula on SOPD that references SOP).

The only difference that I can find between these situations is that *`OpportunityLineItem_Detail__c` contains a formula field that references `Service_Order_Product_Detail__c`, and these two objects have lookup relationships to one another.*

**Finally, the question**

Does anyone have an idea why I'm getting the `Field not writable` error in this situation?

Is there documentation somewhere for this?

**+edit:**

Just tried the other way around, setting `OpportunityLineItem_Detail__r` on an instance of `Service_Order_Product_Detail__c`, and it works just fine.

Comment: Is `Service_Order_Product_Detail__c` a `Master-Detail` relationship? Those are not writeable after `insert` unless you explicitly allow reparenting.

Comment: Other than that I would make sure you actually have edit access to the relationship (`__c`) field.

Comment: No, `OpportunityLineItem_Detail__c.Service_Order_Product_Detail__c` is a lookup relationship, as is `Service_Order_Product_Detail__c.OpportunityLineItem_Detail__c`. I do have edit access on both relationship fields. Just double-checked my profile permissions, and I have CRUD + view/modify all on both objects, and read/edit on both lookup fields.